# How to run Chromium with Developer tools panel or Network Panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am run Chromium from command line and i need of the Developer Tools panel opened always. How i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/HhwKHUryNaA/ByS8AyEg7LIJ

Comment: Yes, is nice, solution. But i hope, more easy exists.)

Comment: If you look at the page, it states there is no available flag for doing what you want to do. I think this is your best bet.